# Bash Script to print different fields in each line

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

My input is as follows:-

Test=variable

Test ID=2122

1 hello till you active

2 This code function 3

And I required output like below:-

variable

2122

till

Comment: Is this a puzzle?  At least "try" to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '/=/ {gsub(/^.*=/,""); print; next} !/=/ {print $3}' file
variable
2122
till
code
```

Explained:

```
awk '
/=/ {             # if equals sign in the record
  gsub(/^.*=/,"") # remove everything from the beginning to the =
  print           # print it 
  next}
{print $3}        # print the third field
' file
```

EDITED per advice by @karakfa and @John1024.

Comment: Hi James,  
@
Pseudo name=hdiskpower8
Logical device ID=2122
1 fscsi2                 hdisk37     FA 10eB  active   alive      0      0
0 fscsi0                 hdisk13     FA  7eB  active   alive      0      0


above is the input data i want to print using awk...

when I tried to run your command pattern it show error(awk: fatal: 1 is invalid as number of arguments for gsub
)

Comment: `$0 ~ ` is implied you can remove them and replace with `/=/` and `!/=/`

Comment: +1. Because of the next statement, the second test does not appear to be necessary.  A still simpler form might be: ` awk '/=/ {gsub(/^.*=/,""); print; next} {print $3}' file`.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to print what comes after equal signs:

```
$ awk -F= '$2 {print $2}' file
variable
2122
```

`-F=` tells awk to use `=` as the field separator.  What comes before the first `=` on a line is therefore the first field `$1`.

`$2 {print $2` tells awk to print the second field if the second field is not empty.

Comment: Hi John, Thank you... But Here I want to print next lines field number 2 (till) and next line (code) as well.

Comment: __till__ and __code__ seem like the third field to me.